# Merge several polygons into one polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, vector-layer

i would like to turn this situation:
[image]
into this:
[image]

Of course it is possible to connect the individual vector layers, but I would also like to fill the gaps between them. The algorithm should proceed as follows: Connect all polygons that are not more than x metres apart and fill the gaps between them.

Comment: Have you try to do a positive buffer of *x* meters (the half of the distance of the gap) then do a negative buffer of these same *x* meters. (erosion - dilatation)

Comment: ok @J.Monticolo , I did the positive Buffer. If I do a negative one immediately afterwards, I come out at the original shape. I would have to merge the overlapping features INTO ONE POLYGON in the intermediate step before doing the negative buffer. PS: What did you mean with  (erosion - dilatation)?

Comment: That intermediate step is the whole point of this operation - positive buffer, dissolve, negative buffer.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick answer. That was easier than I thought it would be. You made my day :)

Comment: Sorry, this step was so obvious for me ... Positive buffer : dilation - negative buffer : erosion. It's to regroup polygons between them by nullifying gaps are shorter than distance of the buffer x 2.

Comment: @J.Monticolo please add your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key processing algorithm here is [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html?#buffer-vectors).

In the following steps, we'll have :

- a polygon layer : <kbd>my_polygons</kbd>
- a gap between polygons mesuring : <kbd>10 meters</kbd>

1. Open the processing toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Search `buffer` and select the corresponding algorithm
3. - Input layer : <kbd>my_polygons</kbd>
   - Check the `selected features only` box if you want to apply only on selected features
   - Distance : <kbd>10 meters</kbd> / 2 so <kbd>**5**</kbd>
   - Segments : more is better, too much is not good, I like to put a value like <kbd>**20**</kbd>. It's the number of nodes added to round the buffer geometry.
   - Dissolve result : check that box to merge the resulting buffer geometries
4. Do another `buffer`, this time a negative one :

   - Input layer : <kbd>previous buffer result</kbd>
   - Distance : <kbd>10 meters</kbd> / 2 x -1 so <kbd>**-5**</kbd>
   - Segments : same as previously, <kbd>**20**</kbd>
   - Dissolve result : not necessarily this time
5. Optional step : as you'll have only one polygon feature in your result, you can do an additional processing `Multipart to singleparts` to separate distinct polygons.